# Autostart jQuery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using a script that animates on click left or right to the next div. It currently works fine but I'm looking to add two features to it. I need it to repeat back to the first slide if it is clicked passed the last slide and go to the last slide if click back from the first slide. Also, I'm interested in getting this to autostart on page load.

I've tried wrapping the clicks in a function and setting a setTimeout but it didn't seem to work. The animation is currently using CSS.

Here's the current JS:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var boxes = jQuery(".box").get(),
    current = 0;    

jQuery('.right').click(function () {
    if (current == (-boxes.length + 1)){
        } else {
        current--;
    updateBoxes();
    }
console.log(-boxes.length + 1);
    console.log(current);
});

jQuery('.left').click(function () {
    if (current === 0){
    } else{
    current++;
    updateBoxes();
    }
});

function updateBoxes() {
    for (var i = current; i < (boxes.length + current); i++) {
        boxes[i - current].style.left = (i * 100 + 50) + "%"; 
    }

}
});
</script>
```

Let me know if I need a jsfiddle for a better representation. So far, I think the code is pretty straightforward to animate on click.

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, looking good so far! A few things that popped out at me: 1) no need to call an empty jQuery().get() (just jQuery() is good) 2) consider refactoring/rewriting your code and creating a simple "animation" function that you pass arguments to. These arguments will determine the left/right animation. That way, your right/left click handlers can call the same function, just passing an argument. You can then use that function for your auto slider (via a timer). 3) Once you've mastered that, how about some CSS transitions/transforms! :) Have fun!

Comment: Thanks Jack, I'll give that a go tomorrow morning. I figured I should have just rewrote it to animate within the script rather than using the CSS to animate it.

Comment: Great! And I agree - having a single point of animation will help when you need to automate, or even refactor to use a different method of animating your elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var boxes = jQuery(".box").get(),
        current = 0,
        timer;

    jQuery('.right').click(function () {
        if (current == (-boxes.length + 1)) {
            current = 0;
        } else {
            current--;
        }
        updateBoxes();
    }).click(); //initialize the view

    jQuery('.left').click(function () {
        if (current === 0) {
            current = -boxes.length + 1;
        } else {
            current++;
        }
        updateBoxes();
    });

    function updateBoxes() {
        //custom implementation for testing
        console.log('show', current)
        $(boxes).hide().eq(-current).show();

        autoPlay();
    }

    function autoPlay() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        //auto play
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            jQuery('.right').click();
        }, 2500)
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rjZYt/)

Comment: This auto clicks right in the beginning starting the slider on the second slide. It also doesn't reset the setInterval when you've click the right arrow so it runs the function if you clicked right 1 second in and then animates it a second after. This does give me a better idea of how to use it though!

Comment: Thanks for the updated version. I gave it a try and it's working as intended. I'll have to change the hide() show() to animation to change the css styles for it to slide with css animation, but for now it works to hide/show. However, it does still load the page with the second slide first. I can figure this one out :) Thanks.

Comment: @taylorqj it is because the `current` is initialized with `0` so when the right click is called the value of current will be `-1`, so try to start the value of `current` with `current = 1` instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example based on my comment (mostly pseudocode):

```
$(function(){
    var boxes = $('.box'),
        current = 0,
        timer;

    // Handler responsible for animation, either from clicking or Interval
    function animation(direction){
        if (direction === 1) {
            // Set animation properties to animate forward
        } else {
            // Set animation properties to animate backwards
        }

        if (current === 0 || current === boxes.length) {
            // Adjust for first/last
        }

        // Handle animation here
    }

    // Sets/Clears interval
    // Useful if you want to reset the timer when a user clicks forward/back (or "pause")
    function setAutoSlider(set, duration) {
        var dur = duration || 2000;
        if (set === 1) {
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                animation(1);
            }, dur); 
        } else {
            clearInterval(timer)
        }
    }

    // Bind click events on arrows
    // We use jQuery's event binding to pass the data 0 or 1 to our handler
    $('.right').on('click', 1, function(e){animation(e.data)});
    $('.left').on('click', 0, function(e){animation(e.data)});

    // Kick off animated slider
    setAutoSlider(1, 2000);
```

Have fun! If you have any questions, feel free to ask!